# Changing AjaxFileUpload control's language

Tags: asp.net

I want to use AjaxFileUpload control in my c# web site. I want my control to be in my local language.  I tried a code below. In my code, some of words are not colorful(for example: Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_SelectFile = "Dosya Seç";) It is like undefined. How Can i change my control's language?

```
<style type="text/css">

/* Buttons widths */
.ajax__fileupload_fileItemInfo div.removeButton{width:100px;}
div.ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton{width:120px;}
.ajax__fileupload .ajax__fileupload_selectFileContainer{width: 110px;}
.ajax__fileupload_selectFileContainer .ajax__fileupload_selectFileButton{width: 110px;}
</style>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     AjaxFileUpload_change_text();

 });



 function AjaxFileUpload_change_text() {

     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_SelectFile = "Dosya Seç";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_DropFiles = "Sürükle-Bırak";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Pending = "Bekliyor";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Remove = "Kaldır";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Upload = "Yükle";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Uploaded = "Uploaded";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadedPercentage = "uploaded {0} %";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Uploading = "Uploading";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_FileInQueue = "{0} file(s) in queue.";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_AllFilesUploaded = "All Files Uploaded.";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_FileList = "List of Uploaded files:";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_SelectFileToUpload = "Please select file(s) to upload.";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Cancelling = "Cancelling...";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadError = "An Error occured during file upload.";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_CancellingUpload = "Cancelling upload...";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadingInputFile = "Uploading file: {0}.";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Cancel = "Cancel";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_Canceled = "cancelled";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadCanceled = "File upload cancelled";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_DefaultError = "File upload error";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_UploadingHtml5File = "Uploading file: {0} of size {1} bytes.";
     Sys.Extended.UI.Resources.AjaxFileUpload_error = "error";
 }
```

.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use either JavaScript or jQuery to change that text:

just add this code on top of the page that you are using file upload control.

```
 <script>
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {

       //By jQuery
       $(".ajax__fileupload_selectFileButton").text("Dosya Seç");

       //By JavaScript
       document.getElementsByClassName('ajax__fileupload_selectFileButton')[0].innerHTML = "Dosya Seç";
   }
</script>
```

and use the same technique to change the other texts as well.